# Prove the convergence of sequences

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Let $x_{n} = 0 $ if $n < 100 $ and $x_{n} = 1$ if $n \geq 100$ prove $x_n$ converges and find its limit.

I started by letting $\epsilon > 0$, as per normal, and choosing $n \geq 100$ as well as $L = 1$

Therefore $ | x_n - L | < \epsilon$, using our numbers $|x_n - 1| < \epsilon$ and since we said $ n \geq 100$, $x_n = 1$ by how $x_n$ was defined. Therefore $ 0 < \epsilon $, which is true. Therefore $x_n$ converges and the limit equals one.

I also have let $x_n = \frac{n-1}{n} $, prove $x_n$ converges and find the limit.

I worked this one out in a similar way, but I feel like my method is wrong. For instance I know from past calculus classes the limit is 1, but that doesn't mean I can prove it. In class the problems we solved were $x_n = \frac{1}{n} $ prove $x_n \to 0$. We were readily given what value L was. I'm not comfortable pulling an L (seemingly) out of nowhere and using it in the proof. Like I did above, with L = 0. It seems too easy.

Comment: A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in N}$ is called eventually constant iff there exists $ k$  such that $ \{ n : x_n \ne k\}$ is finite. It converges to $ k$. Your series has $ k=1$  and $ x_n=1$ except for $n< 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Seems nothing wrong here.

By definition $L$ is just the limit value you're going to prove. If whenever you get a "challenge" (the absolute error between $x_n$ and $L$ must less than $\epsilon$), you can always find such $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $n \geq N$, $x_n$ can always accomplish the challenge, then we can expect the error between the numbers in sequence and $L$ is in some degree definitely decreasing to 0, and say $L$ is the limit of the sequence.

Comment: Okay, interesting, so for the second one I did the following work

Let $\epsilon > 0$, $L=1$.
$|\frac{n-1}{n} -1 | < \epsilon $, simplifying $|\frac{n-1-n}{n} | < \epsilon$ and therefore $|-\frac{1}{n} | < \epsilon $, which implies $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. Therefore taking $n\geq N $, $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon $, so $1<N\epsilon$ an N satisfying this exists, by the archimedian property. so I'd take an epsilon satisfying $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < N $,  therefore I've proven $x_n$ converges  to 1. 

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Almost right. But you may notice that "challenge" must go first, so it's a fixed $\epsilon$ coming first, then for you to find your reply to the challenge, that is, $N$ satisfying $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. According the way you used, it's obvious for any fixed $\epsilon$, there is a $N$ satisfying the condition. Thus you may say $x_n$ converges to 1.

Comment: Okay, so the basic outline is I'm given an $\epsilon$ and I'm tasked with finding an N, so that the inequality $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$ is satisfied for all $n \geq N$. So if someone gave me $\epsilon = 2$, the N would have to be greater than a half. So for instance $N = 1, n =2$, $| \frac{1}{2}-1|=\frac{1}{2} < \epsilon $.

I think I understand now, the rest of the problem set doesn't seem as daunting. Thank you.